# exception specification vs exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

We are in our 4 and final C++ class,  I have been looking at Herb Sutter's post on exception specification and a few posts on stackoverflow indicating that exception specifications will be deprecated in the next release of C++.

I can find examples of how to implement exception specifications, but I am having some issues in understanding just want exception specifications are and how they differ from exception handing.

Any assistance in providing some insight will be most helpful.

Comment: They were deprecated in the last release of C++ (nearly two years ago).

Comment: There are two kinds of exception specification, dynamic exception specifications and noexcept specifications, only dynamic exceptions specifications are deprecated

Comment: One of the reasons it was deprecated, because people could not get it right, causing more harm than good.

Comment: @JonathanWakely "dynamic exception specifications" means old style exception specifications; there is nothing especially "dynamic" about them.

Comment: @SChepurin Nobody ever demonstrated any harm; except the inherent "harm" of having almost useless features that still need to be implemented.

Comment: @curiousguy the term comes from the standard, I didn't make it up. They are dynamic because they perform runtime checks to enforce that the exception thrown is one that is allowed by the types listed in the exception specification. Those checks use RTTI, in a similar way to `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK `throw(A)` needed a runtime type check (that you couldn't even write in std C++ by the way), but not `throw()`. Were typed `catch` described as dynamic catch?

Comment: @curiousguy all catches are "dynamic". Not all exception specs do dynamic checks, so the term was invented to distinguish the old and new style. I'm not sure what your point is, other than being contrary for the sake of it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely A new syntax was invented to block as much exceptions as the "dynamic specification" `throw()`, but now somewhat it isn't "dynamic"? "_Not all exception specs do dynamic checks_" Yes and `throw()` did as much checks as `noexcept`. I'm contrary to misinformation that `throw()` was evil and stupid and useless and now `noexcept` solves all issues attributed to the good old throw spec. I'm contrary because it's a shameless rebranding of a feature hated for no sound reason, like a change of name for a commercial product for the same content.

Comment: @JonathanWakely "_I'm not sure what your point is_" The point is simply that if you hated the idea of annotating nothrow functions with `throw()` in 1997 (the only form of exception spec ppl wanted to use back then), and you still hold the same set of beliefs, then you probably should hate marking these same functions `noexcept` now. Otherwise that's discriminatory. But Herb Sutter has yet to write a rant about how `noexcept` is bad for the same main reason `throw()` was bad. "_there are two kinds of exception spec and only one of them was deprecated_" There are 2 syntaxes to do 1 thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exception specifications ask the compiler to handle all unlisted exception types by calling `std::unexpected()` or the substitute set with `std::set_unexpected()`.

They are universally considered a bad thing.

Common misconceptions:

- "The compiler will check whether you do anything that could throw other exceptions." False.  C++ exceptions are not checked at compile-time. The compiler does not check whether you throw other types, and it does not check whether you forget to handle unlisted exception types.
- "You can't throw exceptions of other types." False, within the function any exception can be thrown. At runtime, if the function would terminate abnormally via any unlisted exception type, the unexpected handler will be called, which has the opportunity to replace the exception with a listed type.

See also `std::bad_exception`.

Comment: Ben, what does this really mean and why is @Crazy Eddie's post incorrect?

Comment: @Joe: Because it doesn't actually prevent you from throwing exceptions of other types... it just completely changes the handling.

Comment: Never said you couldn't throw exceptions of other types.

Comment: "_"You can't throw exceptions of other types." False,_" True. If "you" means the function, and not its subparts.

Comment: @curiousguy: The function can still throw an exception of any type it pleases.  It just won't escape.

Comment: @BenVoigt So an expression in the body of `f()` can throw, but the caller of `f()` will never see that exception, will never have to deal with that type of exceptions, and can be compiled knowing that.

Comment: @curiousguy: There's no benefit though.  In the one case, you ignore exceptions that you don't know how to recover from, and let them go unhandled and terminate the program.  In the other case, you have no choice in the matter, `std::terminate` is called before control returns to you.  Neither one gives you a fighting chance of recovering, but the first at least makes it possible to make a best-effort attempt to save the user's data.

Answer (score 4):

Exception specifications specify what exceptions a function may throw.

Comment: No, not really.  Although I understand why you'd think that.

Comment: More precisely: An exception specification tells you what types of exceptions can escape from a function.

Comment: It's still a correct (and very short) answer, though. Yes, you can violate this "contract", but that doesn't really matter. You can break other contracts (constness or protection) too. This one only adds an explicit runtime handler for that, too ... which is not usually the case when you do something other than you've promised.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions specifications, as the name imply, are about specifying which exceptions a function may throw; in general. How the *may* is enforced however depends on the language.

- in Java the compiler statically enforces this and will reject the program if ever your function may throw something else (unless the something else derives from a specific base exception class)
- in C++, the compiler allows the program, however it inserts a runtime check and if ever anything is thrown that was not specified it calls `std::unexpected`

In general, exceptions specifications are pretty much universally decried because:

- they do not compose well. If you call two functions throwing each a set X and Y of exceptions, then the resulting function should *at least* declare the union of X and Y. Since it soon becomes unmanageable you then need to "translate" the exceptions into some common type, wrapping over the original to keep the context. It is not unusual to end up with a 3 or 5 deep exceptions chain.
- some basic operations may throw. In C++, memory allocation may throw `std::bad_alloc`; pretty much every single STL collection is thus susceptible for example.

If possible, forget you ever learned about exception specifications.

Comment: "_How the may is enforced_" In Java, an empty throw spec guarantees nothing useful to the caller. In C++ it does; **that's enforcement.**

Comment: @curiousguy: I don't understand your comment. I specifically described how enforcement worked in both languages, and your comment seems to agree with my description for both languages. What's the problem then?

Comment: In Java a lot of exceptions are exempted, so many that an empty throw spec is practically meaningless; you write "_some basic operations may throw_" but in Java all of these are unchecked exception. Not mentioning it makes the comparison unfair. Also a lot of basic building blocks in C++ are guaranteed to be non throwing, making the comparison as described even less fair for C++.